# where best to calculate and create a large table to be shown in view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

Based on a couple of fields in the ActiveRecord I need to do a series of calculations which will result in displaying a table (in the View) with around 10 columns and 15 rows.

I don't want to do these calculation in the View so I thought about creating a 2D Array to store the rows in the Model and then just access this array in the View to build a table to show.
However it seems I cannot store an Array in a Model's instance variable so am looking for suggestions on how to best handle this situation?

If there is a way to pass an Array from the Model to the View this would solve my problem.
Tried something like this but didnt work due to attr_accessor not handling arrays?

Model xxx

```
attr_accessor :row_hash
after_initialize do
    makeTable
end
def makeTable
    row_hash = Array.new
    for i in 1..15 do
        row_hash.push(i)
    end
end
```

View

```
<% @xxx.row_hash.each do |r| %>
 <%= r %> 
<% end %>
```

The row_hash populates ok in the Model but I get 'no method defined each' in the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can make it work by adding `self` to `row_hash`

```
attr_accessor :row_hash
after_initialize do
    makeTable
end
def makeTable
    self.row_hash = Array.new
    for i in 1..15 do
        self.row_hash.push(i)
    end
end
```

Initializing `row_hash = Array.new` will create a local variable called `row_hash` so you need to call `self.row_hash=` in order to access the instance attribute writer.

However, this is still a little odd to do in a model so there might be a better way to handle this overall.

Comment: Strange as I think I had done it that way originally and then deleted the code and in this post I just made a typo however when I added it again it does work! go figure...thanks  BUT if there is a better way then I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I would just write:

```
attr_accessor :rows_array

after_initialize { generate_row_arrays }

def generate_row_arrays
  self.rows_array = (1..15).to_a
end
```

You may notice that I changed the name from `rows_hash` to `rows_array` to avoid confusion. Ans I use a name with underscores to follow Ruby conventions.